# Access id active record in instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having some problems accessing the ID attribute of an ActiveRecord model. I want to write a method similar to this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def has_articles?
    return true if !Article.find_by_category_id(id).empty?

    return false
  end
end
```

But I can't access the ID of the instance. When I add `attr_accessor :id` to the class, I have a lot of test failing saying they can't access `category.id`.

Comment: 1) `id` should just be there 2) you mean `find_all_by` (though it's a bad idea because it loads an array) 3) don't write logic this way, `empty?` already returns a boolean. 4) you should have an association `has_many :articles`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write something like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles

  def has_articles?
    articles.present? # or !articles.empty? or articles.count > 0 or articles.any?
  end
end
```